# Help with slopes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a large flat platform that slowly drops downhill using half slabs. it is 6 blocks tall and 93 blocks long. How many block do I have to go across before I have to go down 1/2 block? (If you have ever played Pokemon Diamond, Pearl, or Platinum: I am trying to re-create the bike route)[image]

Comment: 93*2/how many blocks you want to go down in total, the latter of which you didn't say

Comment: He said that it's 7 blocks tall, so presumably that's how many blocks down he wants to go in total.

Comment: correct. it needs to drop 7 blocks and go over 93 using half slab intervals

Comment: CORRECTION: it drops 6, not 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard slope problem... 93/12 (6 half blocks -> 12) = 7.75. If you make 7 half blocks per "flat piece", it'll be shorter than 93 by the time it hits ground level, but 8 will be longer. Unfortunately you can't have a half-width block that would fit the bill here, so you'll have to compromise.

(To verify my logic, I did map this out, and found that 7 hit level 0 too soon, and 8 slabs per flat part hit too late.)

**Edit:**
You could easily vary this by having some flat parts contain 8 slabs, and others contain 7. With that variance,  you should be able to hit 93 pretty easily. The .75 could be made up for every 3 of the 8-length parts, have one 7-length part, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to mention you if I ever release the map for people to explore!